# How to update foreign key ide value in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm quite new to Laravel and I was not able to find the answer to this problem neither on Laravel docs, nor here. 
I guess it's just a matter of how to search for it, cause I'm pretty sure it's a common case.

I have two models in relationship (this is a simplified case), I retrieve the info I need through a Resource file, but I'm not able to understand how to properly store or update info.
Here's a code example:

```
Models\Company.php

class Company extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'blablabla', 'country_id', 'blablabla2',
    ];

    public function country() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }
}
```

```
Models\Country.php

class Country extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'code', 'name', 'prefix', 'tax_code_id',
    ];

    public function companies() {
        return $this->hasMany(Company::class);
    }
}
```

Then I have a *CompanyController* file to manage API requests:

```
Controllers\CompanyController.php

class CompanyController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $companies = Company::paginate();
        $response = CompanyResource::collection($companies)->response()->getData(true);

        return $this->sendResponse($response, 'Companies retrieved successfully');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $validator = Validator::make($input, $this->validation_rules);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return $this->sendError('Validation error.', $validator->errors());
        }

        $company = Company::create($input);

        return $this->sendResponse($company->toArray(), 'Company added successfully.');
    }
}

...

    public function update(Request $request, Company $company)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $validator = Validator::make($input, $this->validation_rules);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return $this->sendError('Validation error.', $validator->errors());
        }

        $company->update($input);

        return $this->sendResponse($company->toArray(), 'Company updated successfully.');
    }
```

And here the *CompanyResource* I'm using to display info as I need.

```
Resources/CompanyResource.php

class CompanyResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'blablabla' => $this->blablabla,
            'country' => $this->country,
            'blablabla2' => $this->blablabla2,
        ];
    }
}
```

So when retrieving Companies (or single company) I get a nested JSON:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "something",
  "blablabla": "blablabla",
  "country": {
    "id": "100",
    "code": "MA",
    "name": "Mars",
    "prefix": "123",
    "tax_code_id": "#$%"
  },
  "blablabla2": "blablabla2"
}
```

If I create or update a new company I send a payload that has the same structure of what I'm getting above, but if I edit *country* id value my company model doesn't get it.

```
PUT Api/companies/1

{
  "name": "something",
  "blablabla": "blablabla3",
  "country": {
    "id": "200",
    "code": "JU",
    "name": "Jupiter",
    "prefix": "456",
    "tax_code_id": "#=%"
  },
  "blablabla2": "blablabla2"
}
```

I'm expecting to update *country_id* field in *companies* table for record 1 so that it matches payload (so going from 100 to 200), but it's not happening.

I could edit frontend logic in order to send only *country_id* in payload since I'm not going to update *countries* table and all that additional info is redundant, but I'd like to know how to manage it in controller with Laravel.

Would you mind helping me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: so are you trying to update both company and country at the same time?

Comment: No, I just need to update Company. As I wrote I could probably just send country_id, but I'd have to edit frontend logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to work with the code now, you need to have `country_id` in the root JSON object you are sending. As this is the way you would fill the id. This is not the best approach in my opinion, but this is why your update is not working at the moment.

```
{
    "name": "something",
    "blablabla": "blablabla3",
    "country_id": 200,
    ...
```

I actually like the approach of sending complete objects. Commonly to fill id's is not good, as it can interfere with the way relations work. [Laravel](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/34d25b0ef827d56952d609174edeee2b0ca01694/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.php#L208) will set your relationships when you associate, if not you are not guaranteed to have the correct relationship after the fill.

Therefor i would fetch out the id and associate the country object with the company. In a logic similar to this.

```
// only fill non relation fields, fill used as save is needed after associate()
$company->fill($request->only(['name', 'blabla']));

$company->country()->associate(Country::find($request->get('country')['id']));

//associate does not save
$company->save();
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe you know a way to abstract foreign key association? In my real case Company has many foreign keys, not only country, It wouldn't look nice to explicit associate for each relation.

Comment: Explicit is better imo, clever code is sometimes harder to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a gist for this years ago that can relate any two models regardless of their relationship type. You just need to supply it with the name of the relationship method: https://gist.github.com/kmuenkel/055f107139d904e30810bf53750d9c6e